# need a "bag of words" type of transformer

Tags: nlp, word2vec, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have a NLP project where a collection of words are encoded currently by `w2v`, to compare to other collections of words. I'd like to try `transformers` which could give a better encoding than `w2v`. However, due to the nature of the data, I won't need positional encoding at all (due to the fact that the collection of words have no order). `Is there a pretrained transformer that won't do positional encoding`?

Comment: If the words have no order you can encode each word separately ? I might not have understood the problem well enough.

Comment: Are you just interested in their embedding layers or are you interested in contextualized embeddings?

Comment: I'm only interested in their embedding layers. At inference time, my data would be bag of words which need to be encoded as vector per word. The words don't have too much contextual information.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the repective embedding layer with [get_input_embeddings()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.get_input_embeddings). Please have a look at this example for roberta:

```py
import torch
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast, RobertaModel
t = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
m = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
e = m.get_input_embeddings()
 
myWordCollection = ['This', 'That', 'stackoverflow', 'huggingface']

#some of the words will consist of several tokens (i.e. several vectors)
i = t(myWordCollection, return_attention_mask=False, add_special_tokens=False)
#a dictionary with words:vectors for each token
o = {word:e(torch.tensor(ids))    for word, ids in zip(myWordCollection, i.input_ids)}
```